# Byte presentation of data in C under windows. Big-endian & little endian

Tags: c, fread

I have some C code, which read some by "fread", but the result is not what I expected. Here is my code :

```
 void main()
{
    unsigned int *data =(unsigned int*)malloc(4);
    static unsigned int ImageData[256][256];
    char *filename= "C:\\Users\\Frank\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\UI\\UI\\bin\\Debug\\bin\\result.txt";
    FILE *pfile=fopen(filename,"rb");
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++)
        {
           fread(data, 4, 1, pfile);              
           ImageData[i][j] =(*data);
        }
          fclose(pfile);        
          printf("\nsize=%d",sizeof(unsigned int));
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)     
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
           printf("\npixel[%d,%d]=%d",i,j,ImageData[i][j]);
        }           
}
```

what I expected in hexadecimal is :

```
38 FC 0D 13 38 A7 D4 92 38 1F 32 B3 38 blabla...
```

Comment: "I can not post a Image because I don't have 10 reputation.Can anybody tell me why?" because you dont have 10 reputation? Earn it!

Comment: So few things - first on the Internet, for the past 20+ years FULL CAPS IS CONSIDERED YELLING. It's usually bad etiquette to yell at people you're asking for help. Next saying "the output isn't right" but not telling us the expected output, nor the output it's giving makes it really hard to help. Finally, your description of the file contents confuses me. You need to provide more information.

Comment: Why 4?  Better to use `unsigned int *data = malloc(sizeof *data);`

Comment: You declared `ImageData` as an 256x256 array, but you're only printing the first 9 elements of the first 9 rows. Is this desired?

Comment: "I can not post a Image ..." Good! You should not post an image until it is really required and I presume this is no graphical application. So, post what you input, what you expect and what you get. What do you get in the debugger? And format the text in a readable way. WITHOUT SHOUTING!

Comment: I'm sorry about my rude and that's a little bit unreadable without Image.I will try to earn some reputation after and post question in better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two major issues:

1. Always check the outcome of relevant system calls, that typically is the case if you rely on their results.

   ```
   FILE *pfile=fopen(filename,"rb");
   ```

   should be

   ```
   FILE *pfile=fopen(filename,"rb");
   if (NULL == pfile)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s failed to open.\n", filename);
   }
   ```
2. When printing an `unsigned int` use the `%u` conversion specifier.

   So this

   ```
   printf("\npixel[%d,%d]=%d", i, j,ImageData[i][j]);
   ```

   should be

   ```
   printf("\npixel[%d,%d]=%u", i, j, ImageData[i][j]);
   ```

Some minor issues:

1. The C-Standard defines `main()` to return `int`.

   So this

   ```
   void main()
   ```

   should be

   ```
   int main()
   ```

   or even better

   ```
   int main(void)
   ```
2. No need to cast the results of `malloc/calloc/realloc` in C, nor is it recommended in any way.
3. Also `malloc()` may fail.

   So test for its outcome by doing

   ```
   data = malloc(4);
   if (NULL == data)
   {
     /* Log error and probably exit ... */
   }
   ```
4. `fread()` might fail as well.

   ```
   if (1 != fread(..., 4, 1, pfile))
   {
      /* read less then expected */
   }
   ```
5. The preferred data type to measure memory and index arrays is `size_t` not `int`. No negative values are needed in such cases.

Some final hints:

1. If you know you need to read 32 bit values (4 bytes), make sure you defines the variables properly.

   ```
   #include <inttypes.h> /* for u/int32_t */

   uint32_t ImageData[256][256];
   ```
2. No need to allocate the temporary read buffer dynamically.

   Just define

   ```
   uint32_t data;
   ```

   and use it like this

   ```
   if (1 != fread(&data, 4, 1, pfile))
   {
      ...

   ImageData[i][j] = data;
   ```

   or read directly into the array

   ```
   if (1 != fread(&ImageData[i][j], 4, 1, pfile))
   {
      ...
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It's a big and little endian problem anyway. Following sovled it.

```
ImageData[i][j] =_byteswap_ulong(ImageData[i][j]);
```

Thanks for everyone.